# Alternative to using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript() in commons lang3

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

I've been tasked with updating our code from using `org.apache.commons.lang` to `org.apache.commons.lang3` and I've found that the newer version of `StringEscapeUtils` no longer has the method `escapeJavaScript()` however we were using this in quite a few places throughout our code.

I've been reading through the documentation and it seems that the whole of `StringEscapeUtils` was rewritten for `lang3` ([see release notes lang 3.3.2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/release-notes/RELEASE-NOTES-3.3.2.txt)) and with this rewrite they removed `escapeJavaScript()` however they haven't said what to use as an alternative in any of their documentation (Not that I can see anyway). Here's the [what's new documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html).

So my question is I can't be the only one to have noticed this and experienced this issue so what is the alternative to using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()`?

Comment: It would be interesting to know why someone thinks this is off-topic because it is asking FOR off-site resources and why they think it should be closed. I'm not asking for off-site resources I have the resource it's `commons lang3` I'm asking for an alternative work around to replace that of `escapeJavaScript` and whether there is an alternative held within the `commons lang3` code itself. Please detail why you believe this is off-topic

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I discovered the same thing today and couldn't find any reference to it in the commons doc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Either of `escapeEcmaScript` or `escapeJson` would be a suitable replacement.

Comment: Doing a little digging into the `escapeEcmaScript` I've found that essentially when they re-wrote the `StringEscapeUtils` class they decided to give it a name change as essentially the method was changing to cover all the ECMA standard Languages such as `JScript`, `JavaScript` and `ActionScript` so I believe changing it to use the `escapeEcmaScript` is the correct approach. So +1 and accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the Apache Commons deprecated page, we should be using:

- Apache Commons Text

  - [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)
  - for Maven/Gradle: 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by modifying the owasp code by detecting when it is htmlEncoding the base64 data tags, which doesn't seem necessary.

I believe this is secure because this code doesn't do the [security checks](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload), but just avoids doing the encodeHTML on data urls. If anybody knows otherwise, I'd like to know. Thanks!

```
  private static void encodeHtmlOnto(
      String plainText, Appendable output, @Nullable String braceReplacement)
          throws IOException {

    if(plainText!=null && plainText.startsWith("data:image")) {
      //Don't touch the base64 encoded images. This messes up the diffing of things.
      output.append(plainText);
      return;
    }
...
```

The following patch for the owasp code will get it to leave the img data tags alone.

```
Index: org/owasp/html/Encoding.java
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
diff --git a/api/app-ejb/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/Encoding.java b/api/app-ejb/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/Encoding.java
--- a/api/app-ejb/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/Encoding.java    (revision c5c815dda1f5c89d2e515d676b8c143591b68d8c)
+++ b/api/app-ejb/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/Encoding.java    (date 1649080667669)
@@ -166,6 +166,7 @@
   static void encodeHtmlAttribOnto(String plainText, Appendable output)
       throws IOException {
     encodeHtmlOnto(plainText, output, "{\u200B");
+    output.append(plainText);
   }
 
   /**
@@ -234,6 +235,13 @@
   private static void encodeHtmlOnto(
       String plainText, Appendable output, @Nullable String braceReplacement)
           throws IOException {
+
+    if(plainText!=null && plainText.startsWith("data:image")) {
+      //Don't touch the base64 encoded images. This messes up the diffing of things.
+      output.append(plainText);
+      return;
+    }
+
     int n = plainText.length();
     int pos = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
```